# Jira Rest API: End date format not able to recognise

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Below is the response for "/rest/greenhopper/1.0/integration/teamcalendars/sprint/list?jql=project=" Jira API. 'end' field value looks long value but when I convert it is very large. Can you please suggest what format it is and how to convert to actual date?

Sample response:
{
      "id": 57997,
      "start": "10012017080605",
      "end": "24012017080600",
      "name": "Sprint 1 *** 1/10-1/24",
      "closed": true,
      "editable": false,
      "projects": [
        {
          "key": "**",
          "name": "**"
        }
      ],
      "viewBoardsUrl": "https://***/secure/GHGoToBoard.jspa?sprintId=57997"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the format is 24-01-2017 08:06:00. So it is a datetime format.

Hope this helps.